# Unable to make my script download rest of the images, if some of them are already in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to download different movie images from a torrent site and store them in a folder in desktop. My script can download & save the images in a folder.

If none of the images or all of them are there in the folder, my script can handle the process of downloading or not downloading.

***How can I make my script download rest of the images, if some of the images are already in the folder?***

This is my try:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop\Images'
if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

items = len([name for name in os.listdir(dirf) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirf, name))])

if not items:
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".img-item .poster-thumb"):
        filename = item['src'].split('/')[-1]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(link,item['src'])).content)
else:
    print("All images are there")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine each image separately.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop\Images'
if not os.path.exists(dirf):
    os.makedirs(dirf)

response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

counter = 0
for item in soup.select(".img-item .poster-thumb"):
    filename = item['src'].split('/')[-1]
    localfile = os.path.join(dirf, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(localfile):
        continue
    # else
    counter += 1
    with open(localfile, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(link,item['src'])).content)

if counter:
    print("Downloaded {} images".format(counter))
else:
    print("All images are there")
```

Inside the `for` loop, for each extracted image link, we check if the image exists locally, and if it already does, we don't do anything with it.

(I also took out the `chdir` because it wasn't doing anything useful. If you want to `chdir` you can simplify the rest of the code to not append `dirf` in front of the local file name.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (Note that I haven't tested actually retrieving the images.)
Holler if you need something clarified.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop\Images'
if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

# get ist of previously downloaded images
items = [name for name in os.listdir(dirf) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirf, name))]

# get list of available images as a dictionary since we need the full src
filenames = {}
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".img-item .poster-thumb"):
    filename = item['src'].split('/')[-1]
    filenames[filename] = item['src']

# get list of images for download
remaining = set(filenames)-set(items)

if remaining:
    for filename in remaining:
        if filename in items: continue
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(link,filenames[filename])).content)

else:
    print("All images are there")
```